# How do I create and deploy a custom DesignerType to be used in a Sharepoint Designer workflow action?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, designer

I would like to create my own DesignerType for my custom workflow action that will be consumed by Sharepoint Designer.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have already created a bunch of custom actions.  I'm asking about adding to the default set of DesignerTypes outlined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/11/15/extending-workflow-actions-for-sharepoint-designer.aspx):

This one may be out of even Skeet's reach.

Comment: This helped me. I've been searching for the specification of that .action file.